# AJAX/JS contact form - hide img

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

(Need some help as I'm a newbie to AJAX/JS.)

Currently trying to create a AJAX/JS contact form for a site.  The form works and is able to send the email no problem.  However, I'm trying to have the following workflow upon the "`submit`" button being pressed.

1)  Contact form slides up

2)  Loading.gif is presented

3)  Form info is sent in email

4)  Loading.gif disappears

5)  Success message presented in Loading.gif place

I've got 1-3 and 5 working, but can't get #4 to happen.

Here's the code I've got in my submit_form.js:

```
if(hasError == false) {
$('#sendEmail').slideUp("fast",function() {
    $(this).after('<img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading" id="loading" />');
});

        $.post("sendmail.php",
            { emailFrom: emailFromVal, subject: subjectVal, message: messageVal },
                function(data){
                    $("#sendEmail").slideUp("normal", function() {                 

                        $("#sendEmail").before('<h1>Success! Your email was sent.</h1>');                                           
                    });
                }
             );
    }
        $(this).hide();
    return false;
```

Can anyone help a newbie out?

Answer (score 0):

**For starters we don't this function**

```
$('#sendEmail').slideUp("fast",function() {
    $(this).after('<img id="loading" src="loading.gif" alt="Loading"/>');
});
```

---

**We could simply do:**

```
$('#sendEmail').slideUp("fast").after('<img id="loading" src="loading.gif" alt="Loading"/>');
```

---

**On sucession of our `$_POST` we hide the form and loading image.**

```
$.post("sendmail.php",{ emailFrom: emailFromVal, subject: subjectVal, message: messageVal },
     success:function(){
         $("#sendEmail").slideUp();
         $("#loading").hide();
     }
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

In

```
function(data){
    $("#sendEmail").slideUp("normal", function() {                 
        $("#sendEmail").before('<h1>Success! Your email was sent.</h1>');
    });
}
```

callback, what you really need to slideUp is the image and not the form since it's already hidden.

change your

```
$("#sendEmail").slideUp
```

with

```
$("#loading").slideUp
```

Comment: Don't you mean `.slideUp()`

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested any of it, but I would think if you change

```
$("#sendEmail").slideUp("normal", function() {                 

      $("#sendEmail").before('<h1>Success! Your email was sent.</h1>');                                           
});
```

to

```
$("#sendEmail").slideUp("normal", function() {                 
    $("#loading").hide();
    $("#sendEmail").before('<h1>Success! Your email was sent.</h1>');                                           
});
```

it should work

Comment: you could also use the slideUp instead of hide if you want it animated